# How do I make the first and second td BOLD in datatable using fnRowCallBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, css-selectors

```
fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                    $('td', nRow).each(function() {
                        //$(this).addClass('bold'); --> works to bold entire row
                        // $("table tr td:nth-child(0)").addClass('bold'); -> doesn't work
                        // $("table tr td:nth-child(2)").addClass('bold'); -> doesn't work
                        console.trace("hello");
                        //$(this).css('color', 'red'); -> works to change the color of the entire row
                    });
                return nRow;
            },
```

I am trying to only make the first and second field bold in my DataTable

Answer (score 2):

As in previous answer said, you can (and should!) do this using css.

If you want only the first 2 columns of a special table ("$DataTable") to be bold, just set a class on the table like

```js
var $DataTable = $("table");
$DataTable.addClass("first-two-columns-bold");
```

```css
.first-two-columns-bold td:nth-child(-n+2) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don’t need every row bold. Only rows which meet a specific condition. I had only posted minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS for this (and shouldn't use it solely for UI purposes anyway). What you require can be done in CSS alone:

```css
td:nth-child(-n+2) {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A-1</td>
    <td>A-2</td>
    <td>A-3</td>
    <td>A-4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B-1</td>
    <td>B-2</td>
    <td>B-3</td>
    <td>B-4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C-1</td>
    <td>C-2</td>
    <td>C-3</td>
    <td>C-4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, you want to add the class based on cell index as well as some other unspecified criteria.  You can do it using `fnRowCallback()` like this:

```
fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
    $.each(nRow.cells, function(k, v) {
        if (k <= 1 /*additional logic goes here */) {
          // $(this) is current cell
          $(this).addClass('bold');
        }
    });
    return nRow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                $('td', nRow).each(function() {                        
                    console.trace(nRow);
                    $('td:eq(0)', nRow).addClass('bold');
                    $('td:eq(1)', nRow).addClass('bold');                        
                });
            return nRow;
        },
```